# How to get 'favorites' to display in finder...?

Tags: macos, finder

I used to have several favorites in the sidebar of the finder window, but today they are gone.

I cannot drag folders into the sidebar, and I can't display the ones available to choose from in Finder > Preferences.  WTF?

Here's a little screen capture of it misbehaving:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to try is to make a new user account and then see if the finder sidebar functions there.

If so, you can log out and delete that user account and then make a backup of the system. You'll want to delete the user preferences for Finder.

```
defaults delete com.apple.Finder
```

Then log out and back it to see if the finder sidebar is working.